# Why program crashes by adding a lot of images to listview?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

This is my XAML:

```
<ListView MouseDoubleClick="ImageList_MouseDoubleClick" Name="ImageList" Background="#353535" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0 5 0 0">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Cursor="Hand" Width="200" Height="130" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image Source="{Binding ImgPath}" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <Label FontSize="14" Foreground="White" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Name}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=ImageList}"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

And this way I add items to ListView:

```
String[] extensions = { "*.bmp", "*.png", "*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.tiff", "*.ico", "*.gif" };
List<String> images = new List<String>();
foreach (String ext in extensions)
{
    try
    {
        images = images.Concat(Directory.GetFiles(path, ext)).ToList();
    }
    catch { }
}
ObservableCollection<ImageBlock> ImageCollection = new ObservableCollection<ImageBlock>();
foreach (String img in images)
    this.ImageList.Items.Add(new ImageBlock(img, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(img)));
```

This code work perfectly with a little count of images, but when I try to open a folder with more than 100 pictures, my program crashes. What I do wrong or what I can do to optimize my program?

Comment: I would suggest to first understand what the issue is. Do you have any exception message you could share ? The first idea which comes to my mind is that you run out of memory. With just 100 images, though - it's a bit unrealistic though. Still, to eliminate the suspicions, please make sure you have a try...catch handler around the code which crashes and get the exception message - which would give you idea about what's happening. If the issue is indeed the memory, and you'll really need to go with what you have, make sure your app is compiled for x64 architecture.

Comment: What error message do you get? And what is the average image size? I would assume that its an out-of-memory-exception. If you have some kind of thumbnail browser, load the image, downscale it, add the downscaled image to the list and then free the original image...

Comment: @mkArtak, @Michael I did a mistake in desribing my problem. Programm doesn`t crash, it freezes and then it`s appearing a window that programm doesn`t answer. This is the problem that there are no exceptions. I also think that so enough little count of images can crash the programm, but it does. And I can't understand why. I can sent you a program if you can and need to check this problem.

Comment: @mkArtak , okay, I`m just left programm not answering for 10 minutes and then it was added pictures to listview, but everything was freezing. And why so long?

Comment: @Sefe I debugged programm and it doesn`t show any exception or something so. Yes, I can interrupt the program, but this situation will repeat in the next launch.

Comment: But you *are* aware that you can debug without exceptions? What about stack traces, values of variables, the line where it is blocked?

Comment: You can obviously only load and display a limited number of images, depending on their sizes, because they all consume (potentially a lot of) memory. You may however get significantly more images loaded when you limit their pixel size in your application. So instead of `<Image Source="{Binding ImgPath}"/>` explictly assign a BitmapImage to the Image's Source property, and set its `DecodePixelWidth` or `DecodePixelHeight` property  to a sensible value.

Comment: Sure, send it over, I'll have a look at it

Comment: @mkArtak , https://drive.google.com/open?id=1A8wuQNyEMWv6gSh9Cd5mZiN-5v15H8h_

Comment: There are multiple issues in your code: You use the UI thread to populate everything - and that causes the UI to free while things are loading. There are many IO operations involved, which consume a lot of time hence the UI freezes for prolonged period of time. I've used a folder with relatively big number of images (~50) and the memory spiked to more than 600Mb. That explains why you get the project crushing with a folder with more photos. My advise would be to use data binding instead of directly adding images to the control and then run all the load on a background thread...

Comment: Also, you should use some kind of virtualization when showing the image thumbnails in the bottom area, as you don't want to load all the images at once. Feels like pretty common scenario to have a control for that available somewhere, which you can reuse. The idea is to load only the images which are visible +2 maybe from each side. Then, load anything else, as the user scrolls....

Comment: @mkArtak , I tried to use data binding at the beginning. It was the same result as with directly adding the image. But I didn't do this on a background thread. I tried to add list items to the UI element, but backgrond thread can't do this. So I suppose you mean some other way to use a background thread. How can I run load images on an another thread?
Also I had the same idea that you suggested but I had hoped that it can be done easily.

Comment: Note that a WrapPanel as ItemsPanel breaks [virtualization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.isvirtualizing(v=vs.110).aspx). By default ListView uses a VirtualizingStackPanel. The two key points to solve your problem are virtualization and reducing the image size. As said, do not load thumbnails images with their native size.

Comment: @Clemens So I need to remove ItemsPanelTemplate? And virtualization it is load images on scroll?

Comment: Click on the link in my previous comment.

Comment: @Clemens Oh, I deleted ItemsPanelTemplate and it`s really helped. That`s what I need. But there is one question: how can I specify a horizontal orientation to my list?

Comment: Well, actually you may probably not need it. Take a look at my answer. I can easily load 500 large images with that code. Note also that you don't need to bind the WrapPanels Width. Just disable the horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: @Clemens okay, your solution is correct, but I don't really understand how works async\await and it's the reason why I don`t want to go this way. Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a view model that loads thumbnail image files asynchronously, and also limits their size by setting the `DecodePixelWidth` or `DecodePixelHeight` property.

```
public class ImageData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ImageSource ImageSource { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ImageData> Images { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<ImageData>();

    public async Task LoadFolder(string folderName, string extension = "*.jpg")
    {
        Images.Clear();

        foreach (var path in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderName, extension))
        {
            Images.Add(new ImageData
            {
                Name = Path.GetFileName(path),
                ImageSource = await LoadImage(path)
            });
        }
    }

    public Task<BitmapImage> LoadImage(string path)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var bitmap = new BitmapImage();

            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                bitmap.BeginInit();
                bitmap.DecodePixelHeight = 100;
                bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                bitmap.StreamSource = stream;
                bitmap.EndInit();
                bitmap.Freeze();
            }

            return bitmap;
        });
    }
}
```

You would bind to such a view model like this:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
...
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Images}"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="200" Height="130">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And populate it e.g. in some async input event handler, like:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await ((ViewModel)DataContext).LoadFolder(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some long time I found several solutions of this problem. There are easy ways, as for me, and some harder ways.
The easiest way, I think:
In my code in the question we need to change code below:

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=ImageList}"/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

"WrapPanel" replace on "VirtualizingStackPanel". In this way program will work as user @mkArtak suggested:

> Also, you should use some kind of virtualization when showing the image thumbnails in the bottom area, as you don't want to load all the images at once. Feels like pretty common scenario to have a control for that available somewhere, which you can reuse. The idea is to load only the images which are visible +2 maybe from each side. Then, load anything else, as the user scrolls.

As I understood this is the [virtualization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ru/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.isvirtualizing(v=vs.110).aspx). Of course, you can tune how virtualization must be. You can find info about that in internet.

And a little more harder way: using async\await what suggested user @Clemens

> You could have a view model that loads thumbnail image files asynchronously, and also limits their size by setting the DecodePixelWidth or DecodePixelHeight property.

Also, we can use both of this ways and it will be the best way, I think.

Thanks very much everyone for your help in finding the solution of this problem.

Comment: These concepts aren't mutually exclusive. Even with virtualization, it may make a lot of sense to limit the bitmap size. And also to load images asynchronously. Besides that, async/await is a very powerful construct that helps in many other situations. You should learn it anyway.

Comment: @Clemens That's why I said that using these both solutions is the best way :)

Comment: @Clemens I noticed that without bitmap.Freeze(); program won't working. Can you explain what do this method especially in this code?

Comment: That is because the BitmapImage is created in a thread other than the UI thread, i.e. the thread used by Task.Run. To make the BitmapImage accessible from another thread, it has to be frozen. WPF provides the Freezable class for this purpose.